# How can i achieve this in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

I'm trying to implement same layout in flutter how can i achieve it, i have already tried using wrap widget but Textfield getting full width and changing textfield width dynamically based on content is not possible

Comment: Why dont you shift the text field right and you manage the selections yourself?
I am just shooting in the dark.

Comment: You can use https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Chip-class.html and https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how to dynamically change textfield width ?

Comment: Why would you need that? What's the problem with that anyway? When the text value changes, `onChanged` is called where you can update the width. I haven't used the Chip widget myself yet, but I guess it does what you need automatically.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i don't think with chip widget it is possible because i want to remove chip as user removing text in textfield.

Comment: Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155254/how-can-i-build-a-chip-input-field-in-flutter) it demonstrates how we can do it in flutter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is too late. But this library is exactly what you need. You have all steps on the website.

It's a library called Flutter Chips. There are the steps and I'll put the link from the library too.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chips_input

**First of all install the library:**

```
dependencies:
  flutter_chips_input: ^1.9.4
```

**Here is the code part:**

```
ChipsInput(
initialValue: [
    AppProfile('John Doe', 'jdoe@flutter.io', 'https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX4057996.jpg')
],
decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Select People",
),
maxChips: 3,
findSuggestions: (String query) {
    if (query.length != 0) {
        var lowercaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();
        return mockResults.where((profile) {
            return profile.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()) || profile.email.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
        }).toList(growable: false)
            ..sort((a, b) => a.name
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(lowercaseQuery)
                .compareTo(b.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercaseQuery)));
    } else {
        return const <AppProfile>[];
    }
},
onChanged: (data) {
    print(data);
},
chipBuilder: (context, state, profile) {
    return InputChip(
        key: ObjectKey(profile),
        label: Text(profile.name),
        avatar: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.imageUrl),
        ),
        onDeleted: () => state.deleteChip(profile),
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    );
},
suggestionBuilder: (context, state, profile) {
    return ListTile(
        key: ObjectKey(profile),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.imageUrl),
        ),
        title: Text(profile.name),
        subtitle: Text(profile.email),
        onTap: () => state.selectSuggestion(profile),
    );
},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter library for building input fields with InputChips as input options.

Please refer below link:

https://github.com/zsoerenm/chips_input