# How to add a widget, like a chip or container, to a textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, textfield

I have a Textfield widget that will be filled by the user. The problem is apart from filling in with text, the user should also have the ability to choose from a list of tags that could be added in between(or end) the text, an example case is shown in figure (In the figure I have used two text widgets and a chip, in actual case it will be a textfield and not text widget).

[image]

The solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155254/how-can-i-build-a-chip-input-field-in-flutter) doesn't fulfill the requirement since it only adds the chips and not the text. I also checked out the [Extended text field](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field) package it didn't work out either. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I haven't worked with Chips but can't you separate the entities entirely?

Like within a Row have the Text("How to add a"), Chip Generator Widget (), Text ("in a text field").

Without any code, its a bit difficult to comment on that.

Comment: No, not a Text widget but a Textfield widget. It will be filled by the user and he can insert the chip anywhere. And sorry, I dont have a working code for this

Comment: Doesn't matter, the principle stays same. Textfield(), Chip(), Textfield()

Comment: It is not like that. the image is an example, the user could add in one case maybe 2 chips and in another case none. It doesnt necessarily have to follow the Textfield(), Chip(), Textfield() pattern. can you suggest how can I do it

Comment: @PratheeshRussell let me understand how this actually should work. How do you want to make a logic when the chip has to be added and when text in that text field? Have you even thought about it? Even if you put some logic into it then how exactly you want to save the mixture of text end chips? Do you want to save it so you can then display it back as mixture of text and chips or as a text only? There's a lot of unknown in your question therefore your question is very weak for SO and doesn't follow SO rules

Comment: 1) There will be buttons with predefined keywords. clicking them will mean a chip with that keyword will be inserted the remaining words that are entered will be string. A sentence may have more than one chip/keyword
2) yes,I must save it. The idea was to save them as a json, the main text will be like "how to add a <<chip>> in a text field" and a json array that will have the chip string (in order). But this was a basic idea and may have to be changed based on the way the textfield and chips are displayed. 
Hope I made it clear @LonelyWolf

Comment: Solved the problem. I used the Extended text field package. Thank you

Comment: @PratheeshRussell can you share your code for this please?

Comment: I don't understand how to use the package

Comment: @PratheeshRussell Would you consider the below answer?

Answer (score 2):

#### Using the package [`extended_text_field`](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_text_field) package.

**Result**:

Whenever there's an `@` symbol, it will be in a `Chip`:

[image]

You need to extend `SpecialTextSpanBuilder` and override the `build`:

```dart
class MySpecialTextSpanBuilder extends SpecialTextSpanBuilder {
  @override
  TextSpan build(String data,
      {TextStyle? textStyle, SpecialTextGestureTapCallback? onTap}) {
    final lookingFor = "@";
    final splitData = data.split(" ");
    final spans = splitData.map((e) {
      if (e == lookingFor) {
        return WidgetSpan(
          child: Chip(
            label: Text(e),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return TextSpan(
          text: e,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        );
      }
    }).toList();
    return TextSpan(children: spans, style: textStyle);
  }

  @override
  SpecialText? createSpecialText(String flag,
      {TextStyle? textStyle,
      SpecialTextGestureTapCallback? onTap,
      required int index}) {
    // TODO: implement createSpecialText
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

In this code, if the text contains an `@` symbol, then well create a `Chip` with that data, otherwise, we'll add the actual text.

To use the created `MySpecialTextSpanBuilder` class:

```dart
Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          body: ExtendedTextField(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            specialTextSpanBuilder: MySpecialTextSpanBuilder(),
          ),
        )
```

---

Complete runnable snippet:

```dart
import 'package:extended_text_field/extended_text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        dividerColor: Colors.green,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          body: ExtendedTextField(
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            ),
            specialTextSpanBuilder: MySpecialTextSpanBuilder(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySpecialTextSpanBuilder extends SpecialTextSpanBuilder {
  @override
  TextSpan build(String data,
      {TextStyle? textStyle, SpecialTextGestureTapCallback? onTap}) {
    final lookingFor = "@";
    final splitData = data.split(" ");
    final spans = splitData.map((e) {
      if (e == lookingFor) {
        return WidgetSpan(
          child: Chip(
            label: Text(e),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return TextSpan(
          text: e,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        );
      }
    }).toList();
    return TextSpan(children: spans, style: textStyle);
  }

  @override
  SpecialText? createSpecialText(String flag,
      {TextStyle? textStyle,
      SpecialTextGestureTapCallback? onTap,
      required int index}) {
    // TODO: implement createSpecialText
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

##### Using a `Text` widget

You can use `RichText` with a [`WidgetSpan`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetSpan-class.html) as a child:

> An immutable widget that is embedded inline within text.

**Result**

[image]

**Code**

```dart
RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: [
          TextSpan(
            text: "one",
          ),
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Chip(
              label: Text("two"),
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: "three",
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: But how to implement inside TextField or TextFormField?

Comment: @user3808307 does it need to be in the middle of the TextField, or can it be in the start or end of the textField?

Comment: Do I need to extend the TextEditingController? I only need chips at the end,

Comment: I can't use suffix, because there may be 10 chips and it will take more than the width

Comment: @user3808307 You can use suffix if you use the Wrap widget, see my edit

Comment: I don't have a way to make it expand, it is max lines 1, and has a max width. The idea was to navigate through the chips with the cursor, as if they were text inputs. extended text field package seems to do the job, but i don't know how to use it

Comment: @user3808307 Ok, I added my code using the `extended_text_field` package.

Comment: Thank  you! I will award the bounty in 19 hours. I am not allowed sooner, Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @user3808307 Sure! did you even get a chance to check that it works :)

Comment: No, not yet :) Also, how do I pass the text that needs to be a chip as a variable?

Comment: @user3808307 Create a constructor for `MySpecialTextSpanBuilder`, and pass in what your looking for

Comment: @user3808307 Additionally, you might want to play with the `split(" ")` method in the example, to split based on full words or whether it _contains_ a word