# Flutter - Input textfield with chips

Tags: android, flutter, dart, textfield, android-chips

I want to have a **input textfield where user has to type email ids and after typing each email id when the user gives space the typed email gets converted into a chip and then user can type another email id**. Just like in gmail when we are typing multiple email ids in the To textfield. I have searched this on stack overflow but found answers which had list and when we choose one item from the list it shoes as chip and same with plugins I found.

I saw this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155254/how-can-i-build-a-chip-input-field-in-flutter), also tried codes of the answers and this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chips_input).

Please tell how to make desired gmail like textfield with chips.

Comment: This code can be help to you 
 https://gist.github.com/battlecook/2afbc23e17d4d77069681e21c862b692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [textfield_tags](https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_tags) plugin for my desired result.