# Insert Input Chips From List<String> into TextFormField Flutter on Button Click

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

I am having a `List<String>` of cities below

```
List<String> cities = ["Nairobi", "Tokyo", "Moscow", "Bogota",
 "Helsinki", "Denver", "Stockholm", "Oslo"];
```

I am taking the cities list and just setting the text to **TextFormField** using **TextEditingController** upon a city being selected in `showCityPickerDialog` which updates the cities string list. Below is the code

```
TextFormField(
                    cursorHeight: 20,
                    enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                    readOnly: true,
                    focusNode: FocusNode(),
                    controller: TextEditingController(
                        text:
                            cities.isEmpty ? null : "$cities"),
                    onTap: () {
                      showCityPickerDialog();
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      isDense: true,
                      labelText: "Select Cities",
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            showCityPickerDialog();
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.location_city)),
                    ),
                    validator: (phoneNo) {},
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                  )
```

What i would like to achieve is instead of just setting the text using `TextEditingController(text: cities.isEmpty ? null : "$cities")` i would like to use **Chips** like in below code where the number of chips inside the **TextFormField** will depend on the length of the list

```
Chip(
  avatar: CircleAvatar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
    child: Text('City Initial'),
  ),
  label: Text('City'),
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I build a chip input field in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52155254/how-can-i-build-a-chip-input-field-in-flutter)

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana No it doesn't answer because they are not building the chips from a list they are just keying in and i don't want to use a library

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add chips inside your TextFormField decoration as prefix Widget like this:

```
          prefix: Row(
                    children: cities
                        .map(
                          (e) => Chip(
                            avatar: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                              child: Text('City Initial'),
                            ),
                            label: Text(e),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  )
```

Comment: let me try, and then how can i get the index of the chip when i press on the chip

Comment: You can use mapIndexed method if you need index of your list item https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html